# adding labels and hover state colors in chart.js (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm looking for a way to add labels to my sections, white text labels (ideally with selectors so I can change them as needed). And I'm trying to change the hover state of each section, to simply show a different color on hover. Cheers for any pointers, below is my implementation (which seems there's so many out there for chart.js)

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
     colors: ['#d92029', '#a51d2d', '#7f1419', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263',      '#6AF9C4']
    });

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'animate', deferAnimate);
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.column.prototype, 'animate', deferAnimate);
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.pie.prototype, 'animate', deferAnimate);    
}(Highcharts));
$('#container2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    series: [{
        innerSize: '30%',
        data: [
            ['Shop', 10], 
            ['Buy', 10], 
            ['Own', 10], 
        ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) and catch mouseover/out events.

```
var text = chart.renderer.text(
        'Max', 100, 100).attr({
        zIndex: 5
    }).add();

    text.on('mouseover', function () {
        text.css({color:'red'});
    }).on('mouseout', function () {
        text.css({color:'black'});
    });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ndvqbsj4/

Comment: Isn't that just the out of the box tooltip?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean /